# Delphi TWebBrowser - how to use proxy with login/password?

Tags: delphi, proxy, twebbrowser

I want to use Delphi VCL-component TWebBrowser with proxy. It seems to be quite easy doing something like this:

```
var PIInfo: PInternetProxyInfo;
begin
  PIInfo^.dwAccessType := INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
  PIInfo^.lpszProxy := PAnsiChar('proxyserver.com:8888');
  PIInfo^.lpszProxyBypass := PAnsiChar('');
  UrlMkSetSessionOption(INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, PIInfo, SizeOf(Internet_Proxy_Info), 0);
end;
```

But i also would like to use proxy with authentication. And here i got the trouble. I learned that it is possible to set proxy name and password using WinAPI function InternetSetOption, an example below:

```
var UserName: AnsiString;
    ConnectionHandle: HINTERNET;
begin
  // Init ConnectionHandle here 
  //... 
  res := InternetSetOption(ConnectionHandle, 
                           INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME,  
                           UserName, 
                           Length(UserName) + 1);
end;
```

I learned that InternetSetOption with parameters like INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME could be only applied to the internet handle that was produced by functions like InternetConnect or HttpOpenRequest.

An answer about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944176/wininetinternetsetoption-always-returns-0-and-getlasterror-returns-1201).

It is not a problem, i can call InternetConnect first. But it seems to be not possible after to bind this internet handle to my TWebBrowser. TWebBrowser will ignore these settings because they applied to concrete dedicated internet handle.

So my question: is it possible to setup proxy with authentication in the Delphi-code to use it from TWebBrowser?

**PS**. An alternative option is to remember login/password proxy settings when TWebBrowser asks for them but i have multiply logins/passwords so i would like to setup them from the code.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: http://microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser-ctl.narkive.com/rgz718KC/how-to-pass-proxy-username-password-into-webbrowser-control

Comment: FYI, your first code snippet is wrong. You are declaring an uninitialized pointer that doesn't point to anything. You need to use this instead: `var IInfo: InternetProxyInfo; begin IInfo.dwAccessType := INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY; ... UrlMkSetSessionOption(INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, @IInfo, SizeOf(IInfo), 0); end;`

Comment: Remy Lebeau, yes, exactly. Actually i forgot to add in this snippet also the code: New(PIInfo);   ..... Dispose(PInfo);

Answer (score 0):

A comment of [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) forced me in to go in the right direction. Answering to my own question, in case if someone will be looking for the response, i found three solutions of this problem.

All the code snippets are available for **Delphi XE4**.

**1. Using event-handler in TWebBrowser.**

TWebBrowser has the event `OnBeforeNavigate2`. Procedure of this method contains the field `Headers`. So we can define some method like:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; 
                                            const pDisp: IDispatch;
                                            const URL: OleVariant;
                                            const Flags: OleVariant;
                                            const TargetFrameName: OleVariant;
                                            const PostData: OleVariant;
                                            const Headers: OleVariant;
                                            var Cancel: WordBool);
var aHeaders: OleVariant;
begin
  if ASender = WebBrowser1 then begin
    if ALPos('X-StopHandling', Headers) <= 0 then begin
      aHeaders := Headers + 'Proxy-Authorization: BASIC BASE64_of_login_and_password' + #13#10 +
                            'X-StopHandling: 1' + #13#10;
      WebBrowser1.Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, aHeaders);
      Cancel := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

...and after apply it to WebBrowser...

```
WebBrowser1.OnBeforeNavigate2 := WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2;
```

This method is based on using the header `Proxy-Authorization` that allows to define proxy credentials for the request. It will require also to set first the proxy server and port using `UrlMkSetSessionOption` as defined in the first post.

**2. Using headers parameter in the method Navigate2**

Method Navigate2 of TWebBrowser supports the parameter `Headers`. So we can define the same header `Proxy-Authorization` when calling this method. The problem of this way is that all the internal calling of Navigate2 (like if some Javascript on the page will call something via AJAX) will go without this header.

First solution has no this drawback.

A code snippet is here:

```
var EmptyParam: OleVariant;
    //...
begin

  // init proxy server and port first as described in the first post
  EmptyParam := System.Variants.EmptyParam;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate2('http://something', 
                        EmptyParam{Flags}, 
                        EmptyParam{TargetFrameName}, 
                        EmptyParam{PostData}, 
                        'Proxy-Authorization: ...' + #13#10);
end;
```

**3. Using an alternative component**

I found implementation of Chromium for Delphi (in active development) - [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) . It was based on **DCEF3** library that seems to be left a little.

It supports proxy settings interface out-of-the-box. It is possible to define proxy server, port, username and password using basic properties of the main browser's object.

So in case if using TWebBrowser is not necessarily for your purposes you can take a look on this component.